# Webstorm git rejecting push due to conflicts files

Tags: git

I'm learning git and I'm having some troubles with git in JetBrains Webstorm. Whenever I try to merge the changes on the same file, the push is rejected and always says it's because of conflicts.

Does anyone know what I might be doing wrong ??

Comment: Please clarify the sequence of actions that you're performing.

Comment: Trying to push to a remote and git is telling you that you have to merge some changes? That's because someone else has already pushed changes into the branch you are trying to push onto. It's like trying to commit on svn and svn telling you that some of the files are not in sync. You have to update, right? Well.... on git you have to fetch and then merge (or rebase) and the you will be able to push.

Comment: Well... there's also the possibility of using --force on push and then you would "remove" the changes done by the other developer on the branch. Technically possible, say, but not the best thing to do unless you _do_ know what you are doing.